# Visa expires before I-94 admit until date

Tags: visas, usa, i-94

My grandmother's visa expires two months before the admit until date on her I-94. Does she have to leave before her visa expires, or can she leave without any problems securing a visa in the future, a week before her I-94 admit until date?

Comment: See https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-expiration-date.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

US visas do not have to be valid throughout your stay, they only have to be valid when you request entry on the Port. After that only your I-94 dictates until when can you stay in status. If your visa expires while you are in the US it does not cause any problems.